# Google query language: Filter PIVOT table with WHERE clause

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Is it possible to use the `WHERE` clause in combination with the `PIVOT` clause in the Google query language?

I started with a pivot table using the following query:

```
select B, sum(C) group by B pivot A
```

[image]

Now I would like to alter the pivot table so that only the columns of the years 2018 and after get displayed. I tried the following query:

```
select B, sum(C) group by B pivot A where A>=2018
```

Why do I get an error here and is there a way to achieve the goal of filtering a pivot table according to specific criteria?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `where` clause.

Please use the following formula:

```
=QUERY(A3:C9,"select B, sum(C) where A>=2018 group by B pivot A")
```

#### The order of the [language clauses in a query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses) are:

**select, where, group by, pivot, order by, limit, offset, label, format, options**